# Importing/Exporting Database With Some Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am exporting database as:

```
exp system/passwd owner=weblogics file=/var/Downloads/dmp/weblogics61015.dmp log=/var/Downloads/dmp/weblogics61015.log statistics=none  

Importing database as:
imp system/passwd fromuser=weblogics touser=weblogics file=/var/Downloads/dmp/weblogics61015.dmp log=/dmp/weblogics61015.log   

SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 


SQL> select distinct tablespace_name from dba_segments where owner='weblogics';


no rows selected
```

Why I am not able to see my tablespace. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The owner name must be in capital letters like WEBLOGICS not weblogics
2) you are using 11g so I strongly recommend to use datapump instead of imp/exp.

Your objects currently exist in the SYSTEM tablespace in the source db they'll get created in the system tablespace in the new db as the DDL for the tables will look like:

```
create table weblogics.tableName (col1) tablespace system;
```

So follow these steps:

```
   SQL> SELECT directory_path FROM dba_directories WHERE directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';

    DIRECTORY_PATH
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    D:\Oracle\app\PC-NAME/admin/xe/dpdump/


    SQL> SELECT directory_path FROM dba_directories WHERE directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';

    DIRECTORY_PATH
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/


    SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY dmpdir AS 'D:\Oracle\app\PC-NAME\admin\XE\dpdump\dmpdir';
    Directory created.

    SQL> GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY dmpdir TO WEBLOGICS;
    Grant succeeded.
```

Now you can export as:

```
    expdp WEBLOGICS/pass DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=WEBLOGICS.dmp logfile=WEBLOGICS.log SCHEMAS=WEBLOGICS
```

Now for transferring SYSTEM to WEBLOGICS follow these steps:

```
create TABLESPACE WEBLOGICS
DATAFILE 'D:\Oracle\app\PC-NAME\oradata\XE\WEBLOGICS01.dbf' SIZE 10M
AUTOEXTEND ON
NEXT 512K
MAXSIZE 250M;

SQL> drop user WEBLOGICS cascade;

User dropped.

SQL> create user WEBLOGICS identified by pass;

User created.

SQL> grant connect, resource to WEBLOGICS;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant read, write on directory dmpdir to WEBLOGICS;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create database link to WEBLOGICS;

Grant succeeded.
```

Now import data:

```
impdp WEBLOGICS/WEBLOGICS 
remap_tablespace=SYSTEM:WEBLOGICS 
dumpfile=WEBLOGICS.dmp directory=dmpdir
```

Now you can confirm it:

```
SQL> select diPC-NAMEnct tablespace_name from dba_segments where owner='WEBLOGICS';
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Now its displaying:

`SQL> select distinct tablespace_name from dba_segments where owner='WEBLOGICS';`

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM

but how can I import it to its own user tablespace?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies. You saved my life. Its working like a charm